# Is there a better way to review your own changes instead of "git diff"

Tags: git

I normally do `git status` then `git diff` to review my changes before I commit. But when some changes are very big, `git diff` does not really show me the best format. So instead, I've got into a really bad habit of commit my work into github then checking my work in their gui (which is fantastic).

Only problem with this method is I then end up making 2 / 3 follow up commits to correct mistakes in the first commit which would not have been commited if I could somehow view the differences in a good format (like github, but offline).

What's the best way? I would prefer a command line option but appreciate that this will not match up to the view that github provides.

EDIT! I should add that I'm on MAC OSX, that probably makes a difference.

Comment: I use the free SourceTree app as a front end to git. One of the nice things about it is you can review changes in a standard merge format, and you can add whole files, just hunks of the diff, or just individual lines as you wish.

Comment: not necessarily related, but for producing clean commits consider also using `git add -p` which allows you to go through the modified code chunk by chunk. I typically use it in conjunction with `git diff` and I'm very comfortable with it.

Comment: You're welcome, happy versioning ;)

Comment: `git diff --stat` might be of some use -- it shows which files have been modified along with added/deleted line counts.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella +1 for `git add -p`, it's veeeery useful. Also, `git stash -p` to stash what is needed :)

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer nice touch about -p on stash. Didn't know it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `git difftool` with a custom frontend.

Personally I suggest meld - http://meldmerge.org/ (works on OS X :) )

It's also usable for merges (`git mergetool`).

Just add to your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[diff]
external = git-meld
```

If you need something more terminalish:

```
[diff]
external = vimdiff
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I have only made two amends. I have added the following so I can still use the original diff tool (until I get my head around vimdiff which looks awesome):

Comment: git config --global diff.tool vimdiff

Comment: git config --global alias.dt difftool

Comment: So now I execute `git dt` for a gui diff or `git diff` for a regular diff :) happy!

Comment: Take a look at `gitk`  as well - it's often shipped with git and provides you a quick but very simple gui.

Answer (score 8):

In case you haven't color config enabled

```
git config --global --add color.ui true
```

Comment: Bloody hell! I feel like i have a new pair of eyes in! THis is AMAZING!

Comment: some other settings(like setting meld as merge tool) can be found here : https://sites.google.com/site/niyazisdevelopmentnotes/git/set-default-git-editor-on-ubuntu